# Passing docker URLs between containers

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I recently discovered Docker and I'm moving my usenet services over to it. I've got sonarr, radarr, NZBget and NZBhydra all running on Docker but I'm having issues passing files between the services. I'm using nginx reverse proxy to map to each of these services.

When I try and grab an nzb from NZBhydra, it fails because it's trying to map to http://nzbhydra:7891/nzbhydra/foo.nzb?ap=bar, which is obviously failing because http://nzbhydra:7891 isn't a valid address.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

default.conf:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /sonarr {
            proxy_pass http://sonarr:8989;
        }

        location /radarr {
            proxy_pass http://radarr:8585;
        }

        location /nzbhydra {
            proxy_pass http://nzbhydra:7891;
        }

        location /nzbget {
            proxy_pass http://nzbget:6789;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
}
```

I would expect the URL to map to http://localhost:7891/nzbhydra/foo.nzb?ap=bar or http://nzbhydra/nzbhydra/foo.nzb?ap=bar

Comment: I forgot to mention, here's the docker command I'm running: docker run -d --name mynginx --link=sonarr --link=radarr --link=nzbhydra --link=nzbget -p 80:80 nginx

Comment: how do you run your containers?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, 'docker start <hash>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comments to your question, you run your containers with `docker start <hash>`.
After you run them all, take a look at `docker network ls` - this command lists all networks. You should have the same amount of networks as you have containers - because `docker start` creates a unique (and separated) network and puts your container there. Therefore you can't communicate.

To fix this, you have to put your containers in one network. To do so you could either put your services into `docker-compose.yml` and run them with `docker-compose up`. For this read [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) section of the docs.

Or you could put already existing and running containers onto same network manually. For this you could use [`docker network connect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/), for example `docker network connect <nzbhydra network> <sonarr container>`.

Generally, to grasp all the aspects, my answer would be incredibly long and therefore I am providing you with those two tips. I hope it's enough for a good nudge in the right direction. I strongly encourage you to read more in the docs.

Comment: Thanks again Alex! I got it working using docker-compose